# What are all my variables duplicated in Tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm new to Tensorflow and am running a basic CNN. As a way of visualising the training process, I build a summary with loss and accuracy in order to view later in Tensorboard like this:

```
tf.summary.scalar("loss", cost)
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)
```

I initialise the summaries as below. *(get_logdir_string() returns a unique string composed of the given parameter and the current datetime)*

```
merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(get_logdir_string('CIFAR10'),
                                            graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

Then for each mini-batch iteration I do this:

```
_, summary = sess.run([optimizer, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x, 
                                                                 y_true: batch_y, 
                                                                 keep_prob: dropout})
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step * batch_size)
```

Then I run Tensorboard and am presented with something like the following, where only the first of each variable (without the suffix) contains data:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssh8c.png)

Has anyone encountered this before? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there is a accuracy/loss per training step. How many training steps did you run? 12? Shouldn't "summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step * batch_size)" be "summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step)"?

Comment: This was all wrapped in a loop of I had a batch size of 64,

Comment: For some reason I'm not allowed to edit my previous comment - please ignore it as I submitted it accidentally.

@YaoZhang: This was all wrapped in a loop of 
while step * batch_size < iters

Step size increments once per iteration, batch_size = 64 and iters = 10,000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the culprit and thought I'd post it here for future reference.

It turns out the I needed to call `tf.reset_default_graph()` before each run.